# Opening a program in current screen with Matlab

Tags: matlab

With Matlab I can open a program as follows:

```
winopen('C:\document.docx')
```

However, as I have three screens, my program does not always open in the same location (it depends in which screen I have closed it).

How can I ensure that the program opens in the same screen as I run my Matlab script?

Comment: [`figure`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) does this as well, but that has `left` and `bottom` parameters, presumably you can move that to other displays (e.g. `'left;, 2000` should come on my second monitor). Whether `winopen` has such a thing I don't know.

Comment: Take a look at the function [set-figure-to-screen](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21958-set-figure-to-screen). It does the job.

Comment: Ok but this is for a program not matlab figure? @Tushar

Comment: @JohnAndrews, sorry my bad.

Comment: Do you have the source for winopen?  Most matlab functions have source, that you can customize.  The second question you have to answer is, "how does one specify the screen in a windows application invocation"?  I suspect that ends up being application specific.

Comment: Source yes. I guess in windows you always know the screen number when you go to settings. At best I was thinking the screen you are working in